# Deleting Database Connection Strings in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, schema-compare

I'm using Schema Compare but whenever I switch databases I see a list of old schemas as well as the ones I want to use.

How do I remove the old ones?

My current solution is to update the old schema to mirror one I want to keep and then it disappears.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the connection strings saved in the registry in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ConnectionMruList`. Just delete the keys corresponding to the conection strings you want to remove.